# Kotlin function return with any one return type from two different data type without specifying Any as a return type?

Tags: kotlin, return-value, extension-methods

I want to allow any one of these two return type (ApiResponse || ErrorResponse). But Return Type should not be a object or Any.

```
fun getAllUser() : Any? {
    val flag = true
    return if(flag){
        ApiResponse(true)
    } else {
        ErrorResponse(500)
    }
}
```

With return type (Any), Not able to write an extension function to do specific action with with two different return type. I want t specify Two responses.

```
In My case, I want to write different Extension function for ApiResponse &  ErrorResponse class. 

Is it possible to return either ErrorResponse or ApiResponse in a same function?
```

Comment: Are ApiResponse and ErrorResponse  your own classes, or from a library? If they're your own classes, you can make them both implement the same sealed interface. That will make it easier to work with the returned value without the compiler complaining about casts or handling all possible cases, etc.

Comment: Yes.  ApiResponse and ErrorResponse are custom data classes.

Comment: @Tenfour04 IMHO, that should be an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a sealed interface that both of your classes implement:

```
sealed interface Response<out T>
data class ApiResponse<T>(val data: T): Response<T>
data class ErrorResponse(val errorCode: Int): Response<Nothing>

fun getAllUser() : Response<Boolean> {
    val flag = true
    return if(flag){
        ApiResponse(true)
    } else {
        ErrorResponse(500)
    }
}
```

Then you can write extension functions that handle either type:

```
fun Response<Boolean>.foo() {
    when (this) {
        is ApiResponse<Boolean> -> { TODO() }
        is ErrorResponse -> { TODO() }
    }
}
```

Inside the branches of this when statement, the input will be smart cast to the appropriate type.

Answer (score 0):

I got a Idea to return either ErrorResponse or ApiResponse in a same function.

By using [Λrrow][1] library I'm able to achieve this like the following function.

```
fun getAllUser() : Either<ErrorResponse,ApiResponse>? {
    val flag = true
    ResponseEntity(ErrorResponse(500),HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    ResponseEntity.internalServerError().build<ErrorResponse>()
    val response: Either<ErrorResponse,ApiResponse> = return if(flag){
        Either.right(ApiResponse(true))
    } else {
        Either.left(ErrorResponse(500))
    }
    return response
}
```

Comment: This [Link][1] helped me to find this answer.  


     [1]: https://betterprogramming.pub/kotlins-either-say-goodbye-to-exceptions-66c66b34ee61

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `Result` class. Either the one provided by Kotlin or, even better, your own implementation. [Here](https://medium.com/swlh/kotlin-sealed-class-for-success-and-error-handling-d3054bef0d4e) is one of the examples of using custom implementation, along with the explanation. This should give you all the information you need.